# How to save custom option field value when create order programatically?

Tags: php, magento

I have been trying to create order programatically, it's working well except custom option.

I have one custom option which reference id is **435**. I have tried the following. But it seems not working

```
$order->setData(array(
'options' => array(
     435 => $customvalue,

     )

));
```

I got above suggestion From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290514/magento-programmatically-create-order-with-custom-option-of-type-date#answer-21303058)

How to save custom option field value when create order programatically?

Comment: you have an additional ")" and it should be deleted:
$order->setData(array('options' => array(435 => $customvalue,)));

Comment: yeah. Sorry, i have entered as wrong in here only. I have pasted that code from test file.

Comment: @DRAJI, I think you should have an order item instead of order itself to save custom options. See here in the public function create() http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/

Comment: Given link doesn't have my expected thought @DushyantJoshi

Comment: do you `save()` at any point? or is it in a `before_save` event?

Comment: After setData(), i have called aadItem() action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer for my question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687630/howto-update-order-items-custom-option-in-magento)

Its working rock

```
$existentOptions['additional_options'][] = array(
'label' => $optiontitle, // Title of custom option field
'value' => $customvalue,  // Value of custom option field
);
```

For more details, you can check on [my blog here](http://chillydraji.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/to-save-custom-options-when-create-order-programmatically/)